Find Red Pixels on a Georeferenced .png (Raster) and Convert To Polygon
I have a .png which has been georeferenced.
There are rectangles on the png that are a particular shade of red.
I would like to convert the raster data (.png) to polygons so that I can find the coordinates of the centroid of each of these rectangles.
Here is my Raster Calculator code: Con((Raster(r"[filename].Band_1" == 230) & (Raster(r"[filename.Band_2") == 2) & (Raster(r"[filename].Band_3")==3),1,0). 
The issue is that Raster Calculator does not recognize the RGB bands.
Error:

"Input Raster: Dataset [filename].Band_1 does not exist or is not
supported."

What is wrong with my syntax?

Extract band using https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm

Is your raster called [filename]? Try replacing that with the actual layer name by dragging and dropping the band from the catalog view, it's quicker and avoids typos. Bands aren't allways called Band_1, Band_2 ... in an RGB TIFF it's Layer_1, Layer_2 .. an ECW it's Band #0, Band #1 ..

Raster.Band_1 syntax is not working in ArcGis

You're right @FelixIP, you can get a workaround in the python window if you type your Con in there, then you will need export the result to a permanent file.

@FelixIP Thank you for the suggestion. I am unable to extract the band using the "Make Raster Layer" tool since the input raster is in .png form and is an invalid input for said tool.

@MichaelStimson The raster is a .png file, would I write "filename.png.Band_1" or something else? Drag and drop does not work from catalog view into the Raster Calculator input box.

Works fine for me.
Input:

Tool:

Output:

